# Display Users and user url's

Tags: users

I need some help I have the iteration working for listing the wordpress users however I also want to wrap their names in links and can't seem to get the user url to work... Nothing is returned to me.

Here is what I have so far.... You will see that I am trying to pull in the user_url however it just returns as nothing. Any help would be great! Thanks

```
<?php
  $blogusers = get_users( 
    array( 
      'role' => 'subscriber',
      'fields' => 'all' 
    ) 
  );
  echo '<ul>'; 
  foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . $user->user_url  . '">' . $user->display_name . '</a>';
  }
  echo '</ul>'
?>
```

Comment: Have you considered using `WP_User_Query`?

Comment: I'll give that a go... was hoping get_users could do the trick though.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the contributors function included in Twenty Fourteen

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyfourteen_list_authors' ) ) :
/**
 * Print a list of all site contributors who published at least one post.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
function twentyfourteen_list_authors() {
    $contributor_ids = get_users( array(
        'fields'  => 'ID',
        'orderby' => 'post_count',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'who'     => 'authors',
    ) );

    foreach ( $contributor_ids as $contributor_id ) :
        $post_count = count_user_posts( $contributor_id );

        // Move on if user has not published a post (yet).
        if ( ! $post_count ) {
            continue;
        }
    ?>

    <div class="contributor">
        <div class="contributor-info">
            <div class="contributor-avatar"><?php echo get_avatar( $contributor_id, 132 ); ?></div>
            <div class="contributor-summary">
                <h2 class="contributor-name"><?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $contributor_id ); ?></h2>
                <p class="contributor-bio">
                    <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'description', $contributor_id ); ?>
                </p>
                <a class="button contributor-posts-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $contributor_id ) ); ?>">
                    <?php printf( _n( '%d Article', '%d Articles', $post_count, 'twentyfourteen' ), $post_count ); ?>
                </a>
            </div><!-- .contributor-summary -->
        </div><!-- .contributor-info -->
    </div><!-- .contributor -->

    <?php
    endforeach;
}
endif;
```

You could also change the [`get_users`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users#Parameters) function to [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) if you need to use other parameters.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain how it helps? Currently it's the same as a where's wally game, the OP doesn't know what to look for

Comment: Already included in the code above `<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $contributor_id ) ); ?>`

Comment: That's the link to the users author archive, not the users URL that they set in their profile

Answer (score -1):

Just needed to use `get_author_posts_url($user->ID)`